# Webpack ReferenceError: asyncFunc is not defined when running bundle.js

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm pretty new to Webpack, and I'm just trying to get a simple project off the ground here. Ihave all the dependencies i need to run the application but
i'm getting the following error when im running the bundle.js in broswer:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: asyncFunc is not defined at
>   App.componentDidMount (index.js?0607:17) at commitLifeCycles
>   (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17288) at commitAllLifeCycles
>   (react-dom.development.js?61bb:18690) at
>   HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:149) at
>   Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?61bb:199) at
>   invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?61bb:256) at
>   commitRoot (react-dom.development.js?61bb:18902) at eval
>   (react-dom.development.js?61bb:20372) at
>   Object.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js?3069:255) at
>   completeRoot (react-dom.development.js?61bb:20371)

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const config = {
  entry:['./lib/components/index.js'], 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude:/node_modules/, use: 'babel-loader' }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

the dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "env",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4"
  },
```

Here is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

here is `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class App extends React.Component{

    asyncFunc = ()=>{

        return 4;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        asyncFunc();
    }

    render(){
        return <h2>Hello from React</h2>;
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

How can I get this thing going?

Comment: First errors I see, move the dependencies of your package.json, outside babel property. Move the babel modules dependencies to a new property devDependencies. Take a look here for the package.json basic configuration : https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json and this for minimal React Webpack installation : https://github.com/rwieruch/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup

Comment: I think you have to add this.asyncFunc inside comoponentDidMount, that's the error webpack has found in your code, it just said asyncFunc is not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t call function directly instead you need add this to function to called in any life cycle method or render

Just this.asyncFunc() it will work